# Where are the breakdowns of the open-ended questions in the 2021 Survey?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2021

Can we get some details of the breakdown of results of the open-ended questions in the 2021 Developer Survey?

In particular, when asked if we visited another developer community, we were asked to name them, but then no breakdown of what those other communities were was provided. What's the point in asking us for them if you aren't going to share the results?

[image: Screenshot showing "Or, in your own words" as a survey response]

[image: Screenshot showing "Visit another developer community (please name)" as a survey response]

Comment: Marketing, of course. ;)

Comment: And if you're not gonna share the results, you could've at least taken like 5 minutes to at least remove the colons, the "(please name)", and replace a few of the generic ones with "other" or something like that, instead of this seeming copy-pasta from the survey

Answer (score 2):

We use free-form feedback in two ways: (1) We mostly use it to guide what responses to include in the survey, and (2) we are also starting to introduce publishing the actual free-form insights. While the second is more challenging, we have been developing processes to streamline this.

#### 1. Response Guidance

For example, this year with our [Operating System](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#most-popular-technologies-op-sys) question we noticed a lot of users mentioning *Windows Subsystem for Linux* (WSL, Linux on Windows, etc) within the first day. So we decided to add WSL as its own response.

Same thing for our [Learning how to code](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-experience-learning-how-to-code) question. We realized lots of people mentioned *books* so we added the *Books / Physical media* response as an option.

There are many more examples like this and internally we have a list of feedback that we will revisit when creating the 2022 survey.

#### 2. Free-form Insights

The most notable example of free-form insights we published is in our "[Other communities public or private](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#stack-overflow-community-now-new-other-comms-names-other)" questions. We did not provide any of these options, but through text processing, we were able to identify the most mentioned communities. For each community, I counted the times it was mentioned or a synonym was mentioned.

- **Reddit** == reddit.com == r/programming
- **Hacker News** == hacker news == hackernews

To address your screenshot of [What do you do when you get stuck](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#learning-problem-solving-new-stuck), the reason we did not include free-form insights is that we were going to do include it in the [Community](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#community) section and wanted to avoid duplicate information within the report.

Our aim was to share the open-ended results in a more digestible format than simply showing free text.

Comment: "Our aim was to share the open-ended results in a more digestible format than simply showing free text." - well, yes, that's what you generally do. But that hasn't happened. There's [still freeform responses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410520/where-are-the-breakdowns-of-the-open-ended-questions-in-the-2021-survey#comment858367_410520) with text copied straight from the question, and several that appear to outright not have been analyzed. I've personally filled in a few freeform fields, and it currently feels like that was a mistake - if there's no public stats

Comment: from it, what was the point of including it in the first place?

Comment: *"were going to do include it in the Community section and wanted to avoid duplicate information within the report"* - "were" going to? - What stopped you?, right now it looks like you asked for [where people go for help](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-learning-problem-solving-what-do-you-do-when-you-get-stuck) in the learning problem solving section, and [what communities they're a member of](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-stack-overflow-community-now-other-communities-public-or-private) in the community section, they're... not duplicate things