# Review our technical responses for the 2022 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey, announcement, survey-2022

> **Update on Apr 13th, 2022:** Thank you for all the comments and suggestions! We will be reviewing everything posted thus far but cannot commit to reviewing new posts.

It is that time of year again when we ask you all to be our second pair of eyes on the annual Developer Survey! Below you will find the choices we would like to include in the 2022 survey. If you notice any additional options that should be included, please post an answer below with the name, category, and a brief description or references to why it should be included in this year's survey. One suggestion per answer, please!

We will be collecting feedback until **Tuesday Apr 12 2022**.

#### Programming, scripting, and markup language:

- APL
- Assembly
- Bash/Shell
- C
- C#
- C++
- Clojure
- COBOL
- Crystal
- Dart
- Delphi
- Elixir
- Erlang
- F#
- Go
- Groovy
- Haskell
- HTML/CSS
- Java
- JavaScript
- Julia
- Kotlin
- LISP
- Lua
- MATLAB
- Objective-C
- Perl
- PHP
- PowerShell
- Python
- R
- Ruby
- Rust
- Scala
- SQL
- Solidity
- Swift
- TypeScript
- VBA

#### Database environments:

- Cassandra
- Couchbase
- CouchDB
- Cloud Firestore
- DynamoDB
- Elasticsearch
- IBM DB2
- MariaDB
- Microsoft SQL Server
- MongoDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- Realtime Database
- Redis
- SQLite

#### Cloud Platforms:

- AWS
- DigitalOcean
- Firebase
- Google Cloud Platform
- Heroku
- IBM Cloud or Watson
- Microsoft Azure
- Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

#### Web frameworks and technologies:

- Angular
- Angular.js
- ASP.NET
- ASP.NET Core
- Blazor
- Django
- Drupal
- Express
- FastAPI
- Flask
- Gatsby
- Laravel
- Next.js
- Node.js
- Phoenix
- React.js
- Ruby on Rails
- Spring
- Svelte
- Symfony
- Vue.js

#### Other frameworks and libraries:

- .NET Framework
- .NET Core / .NET 5
- Apache Kafka
- Apache Spark
- Capacitor
- Cordova
- Electron
- Flutter
- GTK
- Hadoop
- Hugging Face Transformers
- Ionic
- jQuery
- Keras
- NumPy
- Pandas
- Qt
- React Native
- Scikit-learn
- Tidyverse
- TensorFlow
- Torch/PyTorch
- Uno Platform
- Xamarin

#### Tools:

- Ansible
- Chef
- Deno
- Docker
- Flow
- Git
- Kubernetes
- Pulumi
- Puppet
- Terraform
- Unity 3D
- Unreal Engine
- Yarn

#### Development environments:

- Android Studio
- Atom
- CLion
- Eclipse
- Emacs
- GoLand
- IntelliJ
- IPython/Jupyter
- Nano
- NetBeans
- Neovim
- Notepad++
- PhpStorm
- PyCharm
- RAD Studio
- Rider
- RStudio
- RubyMine
- Spyder
- Sublime Text
- TextMate
- Vim
- Visual Studio
- Visual Studio Code
- Webstorm
- Xcode

#### Operating systems:

- BSD
- Linux-based
- macOS
- Windows
- Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

#### Version Control:

Last year, we saw [over 90% of respondents use Git](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-most-popular-technologies-other-tools); this year, we want to ask more about how developers use version control.

###### Version Control Interaction:

- Command-line
- GUI application

###### Version Control Hosting:

- AWS CodeCommit
- Azure Repos
- Cloud Source Repositories
- Bitbucket
- GitHub
- GitLab

Comment: I am so sorry to sound harsh, but can we please start keeping track of previous years? It feels like the list is getting reset to its initial state over and over - most of the responses from 2021 can be applied here.

Comment: For reference, the corresponding post from 2021: [Review our languages and platforms for Dev Survey 2021](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407253/1478931)

Comment: is there a graph/chart of overview of your previous surveys. Really want to see.

Comment: @JovylleBermudez You can see results (and download full data sets) from all past surveys [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/).

Comment: What does "*Flow*" (in the tools category) refer to? If it's the JS-typechecker, I don't see why it's in a different category than TypeScript.

Comment: Downvoted for using code markup to display data.  The only reason that was ever necessary was to display a table.  This is not tabular data, but even if it were, there's table markup now.  Either `* item` or `item  ` would work for a list in regular markup.

Comment: This has become a name-dropping bonanza!

Comment: You may include Pascal and pseudo-code as programming languages. Also you may include H2 and derby as (R)DBMS. As for IDE you may include LiteIde (For golang)

Comment: What was the 2021 insight dashboard built with? The visuals are awesome!

Comment: @BrandonRose thank you! we use [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/)

Comment: How was the initial list compiled?

Answer (score 95):

Imagine that you, like me, are primarily an [embedded software/firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_software) developer in your professional life—what options would you select for the vast majority of these categories?

- Programming language? Sure; I know how to fill that one out every year, and I find it interesting/useful.
- Database environments? No, I don't use any of those (although, to be fair, *some* embedded developers probably do).
- Cloud platforms? No.
- Web frameworks? Hardly!
- "Other frameworks"? Nope. Nobody runs this kind of heavy bloatware on embedded systems, half of which are just web frameworks anyway that somehow escaped correct categorization.
- Tools? Well, maybe, but only because this is a motley collection of completely unrelated things, some of which should probably go into the "frameworks/libraries" category, others of which should go into the "version control" category, and others of which are really just so cloud-specific that nobody but web developers are using them anyway.
- Development environments? Yeah, this is fine. Although kinda useless, really, because most of those choices are so platform/language-specific that it becomes meaningless having them as their own category.
- Operating systems? Sure… Does this mean on my development PC, or on my target system? Or both? I never know. And, if it's the target platform, where's the "Other" option, for those of us who target bare-metal with no operating system in sight, and/or the "RTOS" category?

As usual, this survey, like the blog, is so incredibly biased towards web developers that it's not even funny. Heck, even *desktop* developers get largely excluded by this survey, which is the other hat that I wear when not doing embedded. Please don't forget that not every software developer builds web apps.

---

I wonder what is the point of having all of these curated lists and categories, anyway. Has it been considered just allowing users to enter the names of *tags* on Stack Overflow that represent their interests? A suggested list of top tags could even be pulled from the individual's activity on the site, if they were logged in, but even without that feature, it seems like this would be simultaneously more useful, easier to use (auto-complete), and easier to maintain. A data analyst could easily pick through the collective selections and sort them into categories after the results were in. No one filling out the survey would feel excluded by not seeing their favorite thingadongdong listed. And no one would have to fill out an "Other" free-form text field, which a data analyst would then have to sort through anyway, dealing with misspellings, variations in formatting, etc.

Comment: That's been a gripe of mine about the dev survey for years now. It's very, very web-dev focused.

Comment: I'm not involved in the survey, so I can't answer all of your questions. What I can do is ask a question and make a hypothesis - The question - Are there things you use that don't fit into these categories that is missing? You haven't said anything about that. I... feel like having a bunch of extra questions *as long as we're not omitting something* is OK. It's totally fine for you to have no response to some of it. That doesn't mean we should exclude it because only a subset of devs use it.

Comment: The hypothesis: If you have a list of things to choose from, you're far more likely to mention more items than you would otherwise. If the goal is to understand whether people have used something, even once, a list doesn't require them to pull items out of the ether and remember everything... filling in auto-complete does. I run into this all the time. I list things I do and then someone asks "what about this" - oh, yeah, I did that a few years back but I don't want to ever do it again.... or oh, wow, how could I forget that - I use it every day! A list is lower cognitive load.

Comment: As to importing tags from SO - that only works for highly-engaged users and would also mean that some people might be concerned that their answers were being tied back to SO directly. From what I understand, we try to avoid that entirely. Having an SO account isn't required to do the survey and I'd be concerned with the dev survey seemingly tying your answers to your account.

Comment: @Catija "If you have a list of things to choose from, you're far more likely to mention more items than you would otherwise" but I wouldn't get annoyed that I didn't get to mention the things that I _want_ to. There's no point to make the tech list to be a closed list.

Comment: @Braiam It's not a closed list - it's a list with an "other" field. There's a huge difference... and we're giving people the chance *now* to expand the list because we know it's important to y'all.

Comment: @Catija How is the other field treated? It's character separated?

Comment: @Braiam Not a question I can answer - maybe post an answer asking for help understanding how it's utilized?

Comment: @Catija sadly, there's no indication on the post that we could ask about that since it says "any additional options that should be included", other is technically an option, but it's kinda special.

Comment: Agreed, big iron devs are also excluded. Most of the fortune 500 companies out there still have IBM i (previously known as AS/400). And, there are still quite a few mainframes as well.

Comment: Yep, every year, I have exactly the same Answers for all Categories like @Cody, and same Feeling of "Exclusion", from working in "Macro-Automation" (OS/App/Web-Automation). => Nearly all Technologies included in the Survey can be used and further automated at some "higher Level" through Macro-Scripting.

Comment: @Catija Yes, there are many, *many* things I use on a day-to-day basis that aren't included in any of these lists. I thought that would be obvious, since embedded devs still use tools as much as any other type of dev. This particular list is just biased towards web devs. I didn't want to try to make a competing list in my answer, because, frankly, I question the whole effort to do so, since it'll never be even reasonably comprehensive. Even if I did a good job for embedded devs, what about enterprise devs, like jmarkmurphy mentioned, a field I know very little about? Etc. etc.

Comment: @Catija I don't understand why importing tags only works for highly-engaged users. You mean that the automatic suggestion of tags would only work? Yeah, sure... That's fine. It also takes significant programming effort to implement. It's an optional feature, something for future expansion. The idea of allowing people to specify their preferred tech/tools/etc. using existing SO tags can still work fine, even without any auto import. You'd still be able to pull from the SO tag database to get autocompletion, etc.

Comment: Besides that, we already require users to specify their SO profile so they can get the badge, so it seems like we have already crossed that bridge. It is, of course, optional, but so would be any kind of fetching of your top tags. Since, as you mentioned to Braiam, there is already an "Other" option, why not just go all in? Why bother to maintain this curated list? Surely it takes a lot of time and effort for someone, as noted by this very question, year after year. And, inevitably, people feel excluded, because their favorite thing isn't listed. Having a list implies preference to those items

Comment: Regarding development environments there are some that are very well-known, but only to embedded systems devs. IAR, Green Hills, Keil, Crossworks etc.

Comment: @Catija The main problem is that the survey in the end come to all manner of strange conclusions like "C++ is in decline in favour of C#" or something like that. But if you work with embedded systems, C# doesn't even apply. For conclusions like that to make sense, I think you need to separate it into web, desktop, system and embedded. All these areas are quite different. Similarly, it doesn't make sense to use buzzword terms like "do you work with front end or back end"? Well, what's the "front end" of my embedded system? A serial bus? Some LCD I happened to have in the current project?

Comment: @CodyGray so what option do you need to be included in the survey to include embedded system developers?

Comment: @justhalf I am puzzled at how you could read my answer and conclude that there is only a single "option" missing that needs to be included. My point is that nearly all of the choices here are completely irrelevant, and there would need to be *at least this many more* choices added in order to cover even the *single* sub-field that is embedded development. I could make a list of the tools I personally use, but that wouldn't cover the entire gamut, and it certainly wouldn't cover any specialties outside of embedded. This is why the whole attempt to generate a curated list of tools is in error.

Comment: "at least this many more choices added in order to cover even the single sub-field that is embedded development" that's the answer I was looking for. "This is why the whole attempt to generate a curated list of tools is in error" and this is what I missed from your answer, thanks. I thought you were just complaining that your options are not included. I personally don't know anything about embedded system, I thought we're just missing a few bits from the list, which makes it harder for me to see that your point is that it would make the list too long.

Comment: Semi related, but, the web development scene is the most inward focused of any industry I've ever seen. I've been in several industries at this point, they all knew what web development was (and usually made fun of its tech churn). Now I do web dev on a daily basis and I'm frankly shocked at the level of ignorance of anything "not web", this is the only time I heard stuff like "C/C++ isn't really used for anything anymore", which shows they don't even know the OS their code runs on. There's a whole "web universe" of tools and brand names.

Comment: @CodyGray maybe [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417442/3340702) could mitigate the issue

Comment: At the end of the day, it's a marketing survey. If the largest portion of the marketable audience here is web development...

Comment: Your proposal is interesting, @lifeisfoo, but I don't see how it does anything to mitigate the problem(s) that I pointed out. My issue is not that there are bunch of things which I rarely use. My issue is that there's a bunch of web-dev stuff listed there, which I *never* use, and then absolutely nothing listed that I actually use day in and day out because I do something other than web-dev.

Comment: @CodyGray the mitigation would be partial. Adding a more real-world-metric (dev experience, usage of a technology in the long run, ...) to the naked percent values, we would be able to see how this is related to other technologies (e.g. a 10+ C developer that doesn't use anything else except C itself). Moreover, this will give us a clear view on how some sectors of the development world are more static than others (e.g. embedded development vs frontend web development - just a hypothesis) and how big are these areas.

Comment: @CodyGray On the other hand, my proposal isn't able to solve the problem because - as you said - "_this survey, like the blog, is so incredibly biased towards web developers_". And I agree with you when you say that the solution is to "allow users to enter the names of tags on Stack Overflow that represent their interests_.

Comment: Really? I think non-web technologies are a little bit too much represented in this survey, considering the population ratio between web and non-web developers.

Comment: How do you know what the population ratio is between web and non-web developers, @Nick? Did you take a survey?

Comment: I know I'm way too late to the party, but if tags are a no-go, I think being able to choose what you develop at the start, and then filtering in the following questions, would be a reasonable option that would also show what the trends are in _what to develop_. If you're a web developer, you'd not be shown if you're targeting an arduino or a SOC (apologies if that example didnt make much sense, but you get the point), and a firmware dev wouldn't be shown the web frameworks one. This sounds to me like even more work than using tags tho, so...

Comment: I've been thinking about the survey for a while. I logged out of SE for a bit and I just wanted to say that the survey, the blog, and the site's half baked design all are feeding into an overall product design that makes me think SE's primary purpose is to keep somebody coming back with borderline clickbait and wasting attention and time. People maybe learn here but despite what SE Inc. might say publicly that's not the point. If anything this site is pretty distracting for people trying to learn. I know people said this before, I was hoping it'd get better.

Answer (score 51):

### Version Control Interaction

Might be worth splitting it into at least three: command line, GUI, and through the primary source code editor. I know some people use applications like SourceTree or TortoiseGit to work with Git. Others only ever use what the IDE offers.

Comment: Some crazy people even use *both* a GUI and the command-line to interact with their version control software. Will these be exclusive options? If so, there needs to be a "Both/All of the Above" choice.

Comment: @CodyGray I assume it's the primary one. I'm crazy as well, as I use the command-line and my IDE to use Git. But I wouldn't really touch anything else. I'd say the primary is the command-line, though, as I'd do the most routine of tasks in the IDE: fetch, commit, push, and the git blame annotations. Maybe look at the most recent history. Anything more advanced like re-writing the history (before pushing) or searching through commits and such I do on the command line.

Comment: @VLAZ You're not alone in your craziness.

Comment: @CodyGray I suppose I'm one of those given that I use Magit on emacs and the git binary.

Comment: Many of my colleagues talk about VS Code IDE's Git power and user-friendliness, so I can definitely back this suggestion.

Comment: Agreed with @VLAZ - the question should ask what you *primarily* use. For example, I create my Git repos in Visual Studio because it adds an appropriate .gitignore. From that point forward, I use Git Extensions. Although answering "both" would be technically correct, it would feel misleading.

Comment: Heck, there are still legacy systems in my place of work that we have to *eyeball*

Comment: I like this idea because typing in `git` commands all the time is quite cumbersome. [Magit](https://magit.vc/) should be one of the options

Answer (score 35):

## Fastify

> Web frameworks and technologies:

[Fastify](https://github.com/fastify/fastify) is the rising star of node backend development. It is *the* [fast](https://www.fastify.io/benchmarks/) alternative to express.

A lot of [companies](https://www.fastify.io/organisations/) are using it and the project itself is hosted by the [OpenJS foundation](https://openjsf.org/projects/#atlarge).

[Questions related to fastify on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=fastify)

Answer (score 32):

### Tools

##### Deno

Tools why is Deno under it? It should be directly comparable to Node.js [There was an article on it on this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/22/deno-v1-0-0-released-to-solve-node-js-design-flaws/). It is also literally in the name: "de-no" is flipped around "no-de".

##### Flow

Is it [this Flow](https://flow.org/)? The static type checker that compiles to JavaScript? If so, it is a direct competitor to TypeScript. Yes, TS does a few more things but it does not make a lot of sense to have them listed under different places. TS is listed under "Programming, scripting, and markup language".

##### Git

Is it really worth listing it under this category? It should be under version control systems. Which is not present. Even if we assume that no VCS section is needed, why are there not any other source control systems? SVN and Mercurial still exist.

Sure, later on you say that over 90% of the respondents use Git which might make the other competitors there not worth the time. However, if the reasoning is "no need to ask, Git will dominate", then by the same logic, why include Git?

Overall, I feel that a VCS section is warranted. Even if Git still dominates it, it is a valuable data point. If it does not, then it is even more valuable.

##### Yarn

Another pair: Yarn and NPM. The latter is not mentioned anywhere.

##### (in general)

The "tools" section feels weird. From Unreal engine, through Kubernetes, to Yarn covers a whole lot of ground. Yet there are only 13 entries. It feels exceptionally anaemic. Each language and each environment probably has a dozen common tools used. What exactly is the criteria for something to fall under this category?

Here is a short list of things I use on a regular basis: log viewer (Seq), static code checker (ESLint), dependency management (Nuget, Maven), automation tools (AutoHotkey, Puppeteer, Selenium), documentation builder (Swagger), work management (Jira, Trello). This is a very short list but it still covers 10 items already. I am sure I can come up with three more if I widen a few (sub)categories. And if a few people also suggest more items and more (sub)categories, we can get triple or quadruple the size of the current Tools list. What *is* a tool and what should and should not go under it?

Comment: I 2nd the VCS comments. My company (over 3k employees) still uses SVN, and our VCS hosting is all internal on our own servers. I didn't see either of those on the proposed list

Comment: If a VCS section is added, it might also be worth adding an "Other" option, as there are going to be some respondents (me for example) who will use a system for work that is not worth having its own option for (TFVC for me) while also making use of Git for personal projects

Answer (score 29):

#### Programming, scripting, and markup language:

it would be nice to include [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/): this multi-paradigm / functional programming language has an active [community](https://github.com/ocaml-community/awesome-ocaml#readme) (and in SO for example, [ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocaml) has more questions than the already-mentioned [lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp) language)

#### Operating systems:

Currently the list mentions:

```
BSD
Linux-based
MacOS
Windows
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
```

Obviously for Linux-based OSes, there are many different distributions;
but we might be interested in knowing what family of Linux distributions (e.g. [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software))-based, [RPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager)-based, or with a different packaging strategy) is most used in this or that area…

Answer (score 29):

In "Other frameworks and libraries" this is listed:

`.NET Core / .NET 5`

I'm wondering why this would reference .NET 5 when .NET 6 is the [current](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) (and of course LTS) .NET version?

Comment: I agree. I perhaps ".NET Core / .NET 5+" would work?

Comment: .NET 5 support ends May 8, 2022...

Comment: Just call it `.NET`

Comment: It also leaves out anyone maintaining legacy web systems. For instance, the latest framework that the main project I maintain can support is .NET 4

Answer (score 21):

Under the Tools section, if Yarn is listed, then Node Package Manager almost certainly should be likewise.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, every year this list keeps getting reset to the initial state, and every year we keep reporting the same issues... There are also [alternatives to NPM/Yarn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407272/11407695) that should be listed too, IMO, but at least let's get the *default freaking package manager* in the list :)

Answer (score 17):

## Message brokers

You have included Apache Kafka in "*Other frameworks and libraries*", but similar technologies have been excluded. Moreover, in today distributed architectures they are very common.

- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) is the most widely deployed open source message broker. It has more than [37k related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=rabbitmq) on SO.
- [Apache ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/) is the most popular open source, multi-protocol, Java-based message broker. It has more than [17k related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=ActiveMQ) on SO.

---

This list could be very long because there are a lot of similar softwares and services in this field (e.g. Amazon SQS [amazon-sqs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sqs)).

Maybe could be better to add a general option like "*A message broker*"?

Answer (score 15):

Add a separate category for **runtimes**.

Both [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [Deno](https://deno.land/) are neither web frameworks / technologies nor are they tools — they are JavaScript (and TypeScript directly in the case of Deno) runtimes based on the V8 engine.

Comment: Same for Java runtimes, there are multiple competing ones

Comment: You could even make a distinction between node, deno (engine + platform api + dependency systems + etc) versus v8, spidermonkey, javascriptcore, etc (just engine)

Answer (score 14):

### Other frameworks and libraries

Why is jQuery under here and not under **Web frameworks and technologies**? I know it's not a framework but it is indelible from the web. I would assume it falls under a technology.

Comment: React.js is "not a framework" (at least that's what all the proponents keep yelling at me, I mean, telling me), so it must be a technology :).

Answer (score 14):

Apart from the additions mentioned in the answers, please fix the miscategorisations:

- Node.js is not a web framework, it's a generic runtime.
- Similarly, Spring is not only for the web.
- jQuery, while not a framework, is definitely a *web* library
- Deno is not a "tool", it's a runtime that should be in the same category as Node.js
- Unity and Unreal Engine should probably be in the frameworks category as well

Answer (score 13):

WASM/WebAssembly?

Not sure what the categories even mean so I'm not going to venture a guess as to where this one goes, but a related thing is Microsoft's Blazor.

Answer (score 12):

### Languages that compile to JavaScript

There are some popular languages that compiles to JS used in frontend and node development.

- Elm [elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elm)
- Rescript (former reason) [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reason) [bucklescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucklescript)
- ClojureScript [clojurescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojurescript)
- ScalaJs [scala.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala.js)

Or at least add a single "*A language compiled into JS*" option, so you get a general information without adding so many options.

Answer (score 12):

### Version control interaction

Have a slider to measure percentage between CLI use and GUI use. This would be much more interesting than a checkbox for each possibility.

### Version control hosting

Split this into cloud providers and self-hosted instances

#### Cloud

- The ones you already have
- Codeberg.org

#### Self-hosted

- GitLab (repeat)
- Bitbucket (repeat)
- [Gogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git#Open_source)
- [Gitea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gitea)
- [Gitee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gitee)
- Just a folder at the other end of SSH

Comment: We could add sourcehut too

Answer (score 11):

## Nginx, HAProxy, Traefik... Apache

> In "Web <del>frameworks and</del> technologies"

It's 2022, the world is dominated by web APIs and nobody use a reverse proxy anymore? Or a load balancer?

Most of these tools can be also used as kubernetes ingress controllers, so their usage is.

- ningx, it used as a web server, reverse proxy, kubernetes ingress controller. The [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx) tag has over 50k questions
- [HAProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=haproxy) has 8k questions related
- [traefik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traefik), just 2k questions but it is the most recent one
- Apache is THE web server, not modern as the others but still very common

Comment: What about [squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org)?

Comment: Funniest thing is... SE *themselves* use HAProxy, and yet it never made the list :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine you're right, I read it a long time ago on the great [Nick Craver's blog](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#haproxy-serving-up-https)

Answer (score 11):

In the databases category it currently says "Realtime Database", to indicate the Firebase Realtime Database (I suggested it ). Seeing it without context of "Firebase" is confusing though, so likely leads to people selecting the option for other databases too. I recommend using either "Firebase Realtime Database" or "Realtime Database (Firebase)" instead.

Answer (score 10):

The Graph Database Neo4j is missing from the Databases list

Comment: Along with this, Cypher query language is also missing.

Answer (score 9):

More databases:

- [Amazon Redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Redshift)
- [GCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) [Spanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanner_(database))

You haven't covered testing tools/frameworks/mocking:

- Unit testing, eg [Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock_(testing_framework)) for Java
- Functional testing (built-in), eg Spock for Java
- Mocking libraries, eg Spock, [Mockito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockito), and [PowerMock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerMock) for Java
- System testing, eg Karate, [JBehave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development#Tooling_principles), and [Cucumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software))
- API testing tools, eg [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) and [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29)
- Code quality tools, eg FindBugs, [Checkstyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkstyle), Lint, et al

Build/Pipeline tools, eg:

- Harness
- [Hudson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29)
- [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)

Platform tools, eg:

- [Terraform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraform_(software))
- Morpheus
- [CloudBolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CloudBolt)

Vulnerability scanning tools, eg:

- Blackduck
- Twistlock
- Checkmarx
- Gatecrash
- Conftest
- Fortify

Comment: Yep, very good about "Testing Tools", => + for "Web-Automation"/"Test Automation" also: '[tag:selenium]' + '[tag:imacros]' ("my" Tag, ah-ah...!) + '[tag:kantu]' + 'UI.Vision' (formely 'Kantu', no Tag, [Website](https://ui.vision/)), and I miss a few... // All those "Tools" for Test Automation require some Scripting, often with their own "Proprietary" Scripting Language...

Comment: I think that every language included in The List deserves its own sublists with testing tools, building tools, mocking tools and so on. Including only every tool from the Java or JavaScript ecosystem would not help to get the real picture.

Comment: @lifeisfoo of course. the mentioned items are just *examples* (see the little "eg"?) and I used examples from the main ecosystem I'm familiar with, which is Java.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it ;-)

Answer (score 8):

[Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools). You include Qt in the list of "other frameworks and libraries", so it would only be logical to include Qt's official IDE within the list of environments.

Answer (score 6):

In the *Database environments* section I'm missing [RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ravendb).

Comment: I tried to add this. Unfortunately, Nick deleted it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/417201/7

Answer (score 6):

### Web frameworks and technologies:

- [Ember.js](https://emberjs.com/) - JavaScript framework

  - [GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js)
  - [See Who's Using Ember.js](https://emberjs.com/ember-users/)

Answer (score 6):

#### Programming, scripting, and markup language

- **SAS**

  Historically, SAS dominated the applied stats world, but it's been losing ground due to being commercial (a la MATLAB). It would be interesting to see how this trend is playing out on SO.

  In terms of question traffic, [sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas) is on par with or exceeds many of the included language tags:

  [lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) [f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) [crystal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crystal) [julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia) [erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang) [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) [lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp) [solidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solidity) [cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol) [apl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apl)

Comment: I second this. I've used SAS extensively in my initial years - it was the go-to programming language for healthcare stats. Sadly (not really though), we moved towards opensource platforms and languages - python, apache spark, jupyter, etc.

Answer (score 6):

IBM i (formerly OS/400) and z/OS in operating systems to give a nod to the big iron. Reports of their death are greatly exaggerated.

Answer (score 6):

## OVH and Scaleway

> in "Cloud Platforms" section

These are two of the main European cloud providers.

The former, [OVH](https://www.ovhcloud.com/), is probably the biggest cloud provider inside the EU (despite the lack of [fire extinguishers](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-france-ovh-fire-idUSKBN2B20NU))

The latter, [Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/en/elements/), is another fast growing cloud provider.

Answer (score 6):

As [VLAZ previously pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417201/review-our-technical-responses-for-the-2022-developer-survey/417205#417205), there's a lot of variety when it comes to how people interact with their version control system. I'd add GitHub's web interface to the list. (And, one assumes, the other providers offer something similar.) If I'm looking at a PR, it's often easiest to just make changes on GitHub without needing to pull it locally.

It might be informative to have a "check all that apply" question. Lately I've been working with people who are primarily technical writers. They prefer to use GitHub Desktop, but it's really common for them to need to drop into the command line when there's something the GUI doesn't handle well.

Speaking of which, it would be interesting to see which GUIs are most popular. Might be a bit of scope-creep, however. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**Operating systems:**

- Chrome OS  *(Although it would fall into the Linux-based category, it
  probably should be listed as one of the other options)*

**Programming, scripting, and markup language:**

- BASIC
- Fortran

*(both of them are still used)*

**Development environments:**

- Lazarus *(widely used with Delphi)*

Answer (score 6):

## Ask for `frequency` and `time`

In order to get a better picture and to partially solve [@CodyGray's issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417236/3340702), you could try to measure how often a language/framework/tool is used - and for how long.

### Survey example options

[image: stackoverflow survey mock 1]

### A more meaningful chart

In this way you could clearly see how a 64.96% language like JavaScript is truly distributed among developers. Because saying

> 64.96% of responders USE JavaScript

is different from saying

> 64.96% of responders use JavaScript AND the 70% of them have been using it for less than three years

[image: stackoverflow survey mock 2]

Moreover, you could see how "less popular languages" are used.

> 21.01% of responders use C AND the 80% of them have been using it for more than five years on a daily basis

[image: stackoverflow survey mock 3]

---

> warning: numbers are not real, they are just placeholders

---

### Questions and answers

#### Do you use it? (*frequency*)

- Never used
- In the past
- Just a try
- Sometimes
- Often
- Daily

#### For how long? (*time*)

- Less than 1 year
- Between 1 and 3 years
- 3+ years
- 5+ years
- 10+ years

Answer (score 5):

Will there be an "Other" option, and how would this "Other" option be processed?

Comment: An "Other" option will be available, and [this other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410529/1328704) explains a bit about how it is processed.

Answer (score 5):

Will there still be a category for the types of development people do?

- web applications (front- and/or backend)
- desktop applications
- kernel development
- device drivers
- mobile applications
- embedded systems
- games (console/desktop/mobile)
- developer tools
- plug-ins (for browsers/Photoshop/Audacity/etc.)
- enterprise management tools
- line-of-business applications
- network management tools
- computer science research
- data collection and analysis
- robotics
- machine learning
- AI research
- security research and/or tools
- teaching

Will there be a category to learn how developers deal with documentation?  Is documentation under source control alongside other source files?  Is documentation maintained in some sort of wiki?  Markdown, HTML, Literate Programming, plain text, TeX, LaTeX, Word, LibreOffice, roff, troff?

Missing IDE:  Arduino

Missing programming language:  OpenSCAD

Answer (score 4):

For *Programming, scripting, and markup language* it would be nice to include [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) and [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog), both of which are [hardware description languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language) that we have active tags for on SO.

Answer (score 4):

**Development environments**

The *RAD Studio* item should be annotated with Delphi and C++ Builder as it is a single development environment, but many users, especially Delphi ones, know and refer to the IDE as Delphi (or C++ Builder) and not as RAD Studio and might not recognize RAD Studio as an appropriate choice.

*RAD Studio - Delphi, C++ Builder*

Comment: Well maybe if they didn't change the product's name every two years, the devs using their product would recognize it. Delphi, Borland C++Builder, Turbo C++ (the RAD version), Codegear, Embarcadero Delphi/C++ Builder, RAD Studio... I don't think the confusion here is caused by SO.

Comment: @Lundin You are mixing apples and oranges, including company names. There are only two products: Delphi and C++ Builder which use same IDE also called RAD Studio if you use both languages. But users that only use single language will know the IDE as Delphi or C++ Builder and installed shortcuts will have those names.

Comment: They did call C++ Builder for Codegear and Turbo C++ and who knows what else though.

Comment: @Lundin There was Turbo C++ for Windows released in 2006 and replaced with C++ Builder in 2007 (other Turbo variants of languages were for DOS).

Comment: Complete list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder. They give versions city names too now... the current version Alexandria obviously got the hottest libraries.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, what is your point?

Comment: That they constantly change name of the product(s).

Answer (score 4):

Is really nobody using [Ada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language))? That's sad.

Perhaps the list should include all languages known to mankind (potentially after branching out behind an "others" selection). Some niche languages may be interested in tracking user numbers and trends.

Comment: Some [use Forth](https://twitter.com/PeterMortensen).

Answer (score 4):

RPG in programming and scripting languages. We have a couple semi-active tags around this.

Answer (score 4):

### Database environments:

- Azure Cosmos DB (is an important player in the NoSql market)

### Web frameworks and technologies:

- Aurelia (open-source framework evolved from Angular, growing user base)

Answer (score 4):

## Remix

Reasons:

- from react-router folks
- npm trends says [react-router is installed for something like half of all React installs](https://www.npmtrends.com/react-vs-react-router)
- react-router itself is [being given the Remix treatment](https://remix.run/blog/remixing-react-router)
- the writing is on the wall that Remix will be in the survey in future years, but this is the only time we'll be able to capture the first year of its release in this survey; would be a shame to miss out on that data
- solves many of the issues Next.js has (and Next is in the list)
- 15k github stars (granted, not a great metric for gauging anything other than how many people clicked the star button on GH, but it does mean it's not obscure)
- has a [conference](https://remix.run/conf) already, plus meetups around the world, [10k discord members](https://twitter.com/remix_run/status/1511764574290079746?s=20&t=3HBPG6pDtn6MbNhEkIooMg)

All this is to say that it is, although new-ish, very much significant enough in the web development world to be included in the survey.

Answer (score 4):

## VB.NET

There are more questions tagged with VB.NET than 14 out of the first 17 languages proposed.

It isn't dead yet!

Comment: Is that still true of the last year? Or even the last three years?

Comment: "... It just smells funny."

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how what is required for a framework to be listed under **Web frameworks and technologies** but [Grails](https://grails.org/) is one I use all the time that is missing.

Answer (score 3):

My team still uses [ClearCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase) for version control hosting. When you are using the ClearCase kind of tech, you do not bother if your tech stack is listed in the year 2022.

Comment: Here is [a longer list](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html) to choose from (not all tech names, but a lot are).

Answer (score 3):

To piggyback off the [Bohemian](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417397/11407695): extremely well-known and prominent open-source **testing frameworks and libraries** for TypeScript / JavaScript are missing (the following is a non-exhaustive list):

- [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) (assertion library)
- [Jest](https://jestjs.io/)
- [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/)
- [Sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/) (mocking tool)
- [testing-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing-library)

Comment: [Wikipedia's inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

## Akka and Play Framework

> in "Web frameworks and technologies" section

[Akka](https://akka.io/) is the *standard de facto* actor framework on the JVM. There are [23k questions related to Akka on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=akka).

[Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) is a high level framework built on top of Akka and the [playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework) tag has been used in more than 17k questions.

Comment: we use Scala powered with Play and SBT in our work

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people still build web frontends with JSF:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Faces

Answer (score 2):

If Yarn is included, what about [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) (for tools)? While it isn't as popular as Yarn, [it has 16k GitHub stars](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm), (compared to Yarn's 5k for the [active development repo](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/)). I know GitHub stars don't mean much, but pnpm has been gaining some more traction lately.

Also consider adding [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) for cloud platforms, created by the same people as Next.js.

Answer (score 2):

In the database category, I wonder if [CosmosDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cosmos-db/) should be included.

Answer (score 2):

### Database environments:

[Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/)

AWS and all of its services continues to get more and more popular. Working with its own database platform is something our teams are getting more used to. While it's *almost* [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) under the hood, there are plenty of complexities that could make this a useful entry in this year's survey.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally like to see a question about what kinds of CI/CD tooling users are using. I would be curious as to what kinds of technologies people are using to build and deploy their applications, including **not** using any tools at all. Preferably, the options would be similar to:

- [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29)
- [GitHub Actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#Scope)
- GitLab CI/CD
- [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/about/)
- [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server)
- [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/)
- [Phabricator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phabricator)
- [Travis CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travis_CI)
- Other
- None

Comment: `CI` = "Continuous Integration", I guess...? + `CD` stands for...?, oh...!,  =>  "Continuous Development" maybe...?, or "Continuous Deployment"...?

Comment: Continuous Delivery or Continuous Deployment

Comment: "GitLab CI/CD" appears to be (confusingly) ***the actual name of it***: *"GitLab CI/CD is a tool for software development using the continuous methodologies: Continuous Integration (CI), Continuous Delivery (CD), and Continuous Deployment (CD)"*

Comment: Yep, that is correct

Answer (score 2):

## Web Frameworks

I'd like to nominate [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/) for inclusion. Sinatra is another popular Ruby framework for web applications. The relationship between Sinatra and Rails is comparable to that of Flask and Django in the Python community. The former in both cases is highly flexible and leaves you to make most decisions, while the latter in both cases is larger and much more opinionated. Since we include both Flask and Django, it makes sense to include both in Ruby's case too.

Answer (score 2):

Would be interesting to see **OpenStack** in Cloud Platforms section, how many are using this stack instead of one of the proprietary alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

**[Salesforce Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm)** and **[SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm)** in *Programming, scripting, and markup language*

It would be interesting to see the intersection between full time Salesforce developers, part time Salesforce developers, and other tools and languages they use along with these languages.

Comment: Oracle abbreviates it's Application Express to Apex, so "Salesforce Apex" may be better

Comment: @GaryMyers when I list it on my CV I put it like that so I'm not sure why I didn't think to do that here. But I agree.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM suite is missing, if you want to capture people working on more legacy/enterprise-y-type things - MQ, ACE/IIB.

And are you interested in application servers - Tomcat, Websphere...?

Answer (score 0):

[Nuxt.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxt.js) was not in the list of frameworks. Anyway, Vue.js was mentioned, but I was trying to find Nuxt.js in the list.

I use Nuxt.js in front end development. It is easy, but it has broad enough capabilities that keeps me in fun using it.

Comment: [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/), [Nuxt.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxt.js). What is [the difference](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f)?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what @[VLAZ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) said, it might be interesting to add if people use pull requests/merge requests and if they do them via IDE, command-line, desktop-GUI or WebGUI (directly in GitHub, GitLab, etc.).

Also, there might be different approaches to merging (e.g., fast forward), branching (e.g., [GitFlow](https://www.gitflow.com/)), rebasing and many more.

I don't know if it's huge enough to be added, but I used to work with the programming language [ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion) for quite some time.

When it comes to databases, I didn't see any [graph databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases) in the list. I, for example, use [Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neo4j).

Answer (score 0):

## Cloud Platforms: Linode

[Linode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linode) is one of the largest cloud server providers and should probably be on this list.

Comment: (It was [recently acquired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linode#History) by [Akamai Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies#Controversies).)

Answer (score 0):

### Additional Database Environments:

- Databricks
- Snowflake

(To be fair, Apache Spark is mentioned in other frameworks)

Comment: *Databricks* and *Snowflake* are both names of a company. What [products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Databricks#Products)? *Databricks SQL*, *Delta Lake*, *MLflow* or *Koalas*? Or something else? And *Snowflake Data Cloud*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, That's a good question.  For Databricks, I would probably use their Delta Lakehouse moniker.

Answer (score 0):

For programming languages, you may include [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29). I learn with it. And is not so dead (at least not like [J2ME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition)).

Also [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), that is used for solving problems employing logical and mathematical abstractions without dealing with the burden of configuring a computer. I guess it can be taking into account. It is very important for learning, and it shows a way.

Comment: `Turbo Pascal` is much more modern than `Pascal` [sic], I learned Programming euh..., 35 years ago now, oops...!, => with `Pascal` & `Turbo Pascal`... And yep indeed, what you call `Pseudo Code` was called `Algorithmic` then, and `Algorithmic` is "the Basis" for understanding any Programming Language... Still True 35 years later...

Answer (score 0):

SvelteKit is different from Svelte, akin to how Next.JS is listed as separate from React. SvelteKit is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

Linode is also a widely used cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Builder is not listed as an IDE.

Comment: First of all, could you not have posted these three suggestions as one single answer? Second of all, the question clearly states that they stopped collecting feedback two weeks ago.

Comment: They are three completely separate suggestions and I missed the notice.

Answer (score -1):

[SignalR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR) is a great technology and I think it should be included?

Answer (score -1):

In the ***Tools*** section there seems to be a typo and instead of *`Puppet`* it should have been *`Puppeteer`*

Comment: *Why*? ***[They](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29)*** ***both*** [exist](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/). Frequency of use/popularity?

Comment: Maybe a call for companies to not use [common nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) for product names. Some are *genuinely* afraid of [snakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) (or [spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnophobia) or [clowns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_clown)).

Comment: [This one](https://psychtimes.com/pupaphobia-fear-of-puppets/) is covered as well.

Answer (score -1):

**Tools to diff and merge** deserve to have their own category.

Entering `git difftool --tool-help` in git shows those that are pre-configured by default:

> vimdiff, vimdiff2, vimdiff3, araxis, bc, bc3, codecompare, deltawalker, diffmerge, diffuse, ecmerge, emerge, examdiff, guiffy, gvimdiff, gvimdiff2, gvimdiff3, kdiff3, kompare, meld, opendiff, p4merge, smerge, tkdiff, winmerge, xxdiff

These are too many, but I'd certainly include **Beyond Compare, kdiff3, Kompare, Meld, Winmerge**.

Then there are web-based tools in GitLab, GitHub, and so on.

And tools like these can be part of an IDE, possibly as external plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Which programming language do we use? All of us, at least use one of them, but for what?

I think it is better to split it in usage areas. I use Python for [data science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science) and .NET for Web development and Ruby is my Swiss Army knife, but I don’t like Python for Web... Which programming language, alone, does not make a sense for me.

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to see MySQL split into MySQL5.x and MySQL8 - version 8 is a far more full-featured SQL implementation and it would be interesting to know how many users have migrated to it.