# What tech is "Flow" in the 2022 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, survey, survey-2022

In the **Which developer tools have you done extensive development work in...** question, there is a piece of tech listed named "Flow", however, it's very unclear which "Flow" this is referring to.

*[Aside: Has there been consideration for adding info bubbles or tooltips that link to the canonical repos or project homepages for the named pieces of tech in the survey to disambiguate?]*

Most of the other tools in this list are very well known DevOps or package management related (excluding Unity and Unreal Engine).  However, I cannot seem to find any tools named Flow that in either of those categories.  [It also seems odd to group these 3 disparate categories into one category???]

There are quite a few semi-popular projects named Flow but none I found seem like the others on this list.  Here are the ones I found with their official repo descriptions:

| repo | description |
| --- | --- |
| https://github.com/totaljs/flow | Flow |
| https://github.com/onflow/flow | Flow is a fast, secure, and developer-friendly blockchain built to support the next generation of games, apps, and the digital assets that power them |
| https://github.com/neos/flow-development-collection | The unified repository containing the Flow core packages, used for Flow development. |
| https://github.com/flow-project/flow | Computational framework for reinforcement learning in traffic control |
| https://github.com/facebook/flow | Adds static typing to JavaScript to improve developer productivity and code quality. |
| https://github.com/dashbitco/flow | Computational parallel flows on top of GenStage |

From searching, I saw this was also asked by several people in [Review our technical responses for the 2022 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417201/review-our-technical-responses-for-the-2022-developer-survey) but never answered.

I also asked this question [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/kicksopenminds/status/1530347162688684033) in reply to @StackOverflow, but it does not appear that replies to their tweet are being monitored.

It would be great to disambiguate common names like this for the integrity of the survey results in the future.

Comment: Oh, I would've assumed it meant Power Automate

Comment: It's also considered [too ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flow/info) to be used on the main site

Comment: Just go with the flow ... ?

Comment: [The Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow#Computing) lists, among others, Calligra Flow (free diagramming software), Microsoft Flow (renamed to Power Automate in 2019), Neos Flow (PHP web application framework), webMethods Flow (a graphical programming language), FLOW (programming language from the 1970s), and Flow (a web browser).

Comment: I would have assumed it was Facebook's answer to TypeScript: https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/

Comment: [java.util.concurrent.Flow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html)?